# How to plot a graph to see the accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, classification

I am using the `tflite_model_maker`.

```
from tflite_model_maker import model_spec
from tflite_model_maker import image_classifier
from tflite_model_maker.config import ExportFormat
from tflite_model_maker.config import QuantizationConfig
from tflite_model_maker.image_classifier import DataLoader
```

I want to train the model and want to plot a graph to see the performance of the model but this one doesn't have `history`,

```
model = image_classifier.create(train_data,
                                model_spec = model_spec.get('efficientnet_lite4'),
                                validation_data=validation_data,
                                batch_size = 32,
                                epochs=200,
                                train_whole_model = True,
                                dropout_rate=0.25,
                                learning_rate = 0.01,
                                momentum = 0.9,
                                shuffle=True,
                                )
```

what should I do?

Comment: @AloneTogether  Yes, your answer helped me a lot. i thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little different than what you're used to, but you can access the metrics you want as follows:

```py
model.history.history['loss']
model.history.history['accuracy']
model.history.history['val_loss']
model.history.history['val_accuracy']
```